# Convert this curl to multi PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have this code and I want made 10 curl connections like this with multi but I don't know how to that with this specific code:

What the code does?

1. Make a curl requiest to an .asp page
2. Uses the result to send some data in a form ($ciudad) then the page get this submit and make an internal request and show an result.
3. Output the final result of that.

   ```
   function curl($header,$encoded,$cookie){
     $options = array(
       CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 120,    
       //CURLOPT_REFERER           => '',
       //CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER        => $header,
       CURLOPT_COOKIE          =>  $cookie,
       CURLOPT_POST            => true,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $encoded,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,     
       CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,    
       CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,     
     );
     $ch = curl_init("http://procesos.ramajudicial.gov.co/consultaprocesos/consultap.aspx"); 
     curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
     $output = curl_exec($ch); 
     curl_close($ch);
     return $output;
   }

   $cookie = "";
   foreach($_COOKIE as $k => $v)
     $cookie .= $k."=".$v.";";
     $cookie = substr($cookie,0,strlen($cookie)-1);

     $encoded = '';
     foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
       $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
     }

     $lk = "http://procesos.ramajudicial.gov.co/consultaprocesos/";

     $header[] = 'User-Agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
     $header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text /html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
     $header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5'; 
     $header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'; 
     $header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
     $header[] = 'Cookie : '.$cookie;
     $header[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

     $output = curl($header,$encoded,$cookie);

     $CIUDAD = urlencode("Medellin"); // to change
     $CORPORACION = urlencode("JUZGADOS CIVILES MUNICIPALES DE MEDELLIN"); // to change
     $DIGITOS = $numsus; 

     // BEGIN STEP 1
     $__VIEWSTATE = 'id="__VIEWSTATE" value="';
     $i = stripos($output,$__VIEWSTATE) + strlen($__VIEWSTATE);
     $j = stripos($output,'"',$i);
     $__VIEWSTATE = substr($output,$i,$j-$i);

     $__EVENTVALIDATION = 'id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="';
     $i = stripos($output,$__EVENTVALIDATION) + strlen($__EVENTVALIDATION);
     $j = stripos($output,'"',$i);
     $__EVENTVALIDATION = substr($output,$i,$j-$i);

     $encoded = '__EVENTTARGET=DropDownList1&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE='.urlencode($__VIEWSTATE).'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.urlencode($__EVENTVALIDATION).'&DropDownList1='.$CIUDAD.'&TextBox13=';

     $output = curl($header,$encoded,$cookie);
   ```

Comment: Your function is impossible to read. Please format it

Comment: Done! why stackoverflow don't have and php tag to add code? oh!.

Comment: Not a PHP tag, but it does have a code button. Or you just indent your code by four spaces

Comment: multicurl has been a pain in my a** for the last few years. If you can circumvent this problem by running php binaries in parallel or using crontab entries to run PHP and saving the output do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good if you could just have ten threads using whatever works best for you, file_get_contents most probably ...

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

You can have Threads :)

Enjoy ...

Answer (score 0):

Multi curl is sometimes hard to grasp at first, may I warmly suggest to checkout out  Pete Wardens PHP https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl implementation.  This takes the abstraction away.

You basically need to implement a callback function to fire when the download completes.  Writing to a temp directory for example and when it's all done your main program can check for the content and handle it from there on.